# Remove indentation, but keep line breaks in template literal

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I have the following template literal:

```
let message = `
    1 call
    Alert time: 6:00:57 PM
    `
```

I've tried various answers from here on SO but for the API I'm working with, none of those solutions work correctly. Those solutions seem to be causing the line breaks after the opening backtick and the ending backtick to be removed along with the indentation.

Because this is happening the API I'm working with is treating the template literal as a single string with no line breaks.

How can I retain all of the line breaks but remove only the indentation in front of `1 call` and `Alert time: 6:00:57 PM`?

My expected output would be this:

```
1 call
Alert time: 6:00:57 PM
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regular expression can match space characters at the beginning of the line and replace them with nothing, leaving the newlines alone:

```
message.replace(/^ +/gm, '')
```

Demo:

```js
let message = `
    1 call
    Alert time: 6:00:57 PM
    `
document.querySelector('textarea').value = message.replace(/^ +/gm, '');
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've tried this already, but it caused the same problem I described. I will try again and update in the comments.

Comment: Yes, the same problem is still happening with this answer.

Comment: Works just fine on my end, the line breaks are all preserved. `^ +` will not remove newlines. It will only match literal space characters at the beginning of a line.

Comment: The issue is likely something with the API I'm working with. Unfortunately, I can't see the code for that API to understand why it isn't working as expected. The line breaks before the first backtick and last backtick are getting removed. I'm going to try adding extra line breaks.

Comment: If the code really is as you've shown in the question, then the code in my answer will produce the output you're looking for. If your code is not actually what's in the question, please edit the question to include it.

Comment: The API I'm working with wants a string on a single line. I believe that by using template literals, I'm kind of 'hacking' it so I can add line breaks. Without your answer, I can get the line breaks I want, but the indentation is there. With your answer the API treats the template literal as a single line string.

Comment: So, I think this is a limitation of the API... I'm going to accept your answer. It's frustrating that the API has this limitation though.

Answer (score 0):

I would `split` the string by all the new lines `\n`, then trim the items in the array to remove the spaces then join them again with new lines `\n`. The `filter` is to remove the items in the `split` array that could be empty strings

```js
let message = `
    1 call
    Alert time: 6:00:57 PM
    `;
    
console.log(['', ...message.split('\n').filter(Boolean).map(str => str.trim()), ''].join('\n'));
```

Comment: OP wants 4 lines. One empty line, one line with `'1 call'`, one line with `'Alert time: 6:00:57 PM'` and one empty line. You should remove `filter(Boolean)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are, of course, a infinte ways to get to your solution. To make only the indent of the content disappear you can use the following method with your template strings. This ensures that only the indent created by the template string disappears, but the basic formatting remains intact.

```js
function trimIndent(strings, ...values) {
    const result = new Array(strings.length);
    result[0] = strings[0].replace(/^\n/, '');
    const endIndex = strings.length - 1;
    result[endIndex] = strings[endIndex].replace(/\n$/, '');

    var indent = result[0].match(/^\s+/g);
    result[0] = result[0].replace(/^\s+/, '');

    for (let i = 0, m = result.length; i < m; i++) {
        var input = result[i] ?? strings[i];
        result[i] = input.replace(new RegExp('\n' + indent, "gm"), '\n');
    }

    return result.flatMap((value, index) => {
        return value + (index < values.length ? values[index] : '')
    }).join("");
}

// example call:
var user = {
  id: 10,
  name: "Kevin",
  
}
if (true) {
  console.log(trimIndent`
      <div>
        <span>ID: ${user.id}</span>
        <span>
          Username: ${user.name}
        </span>
      </div>
  `);
}
```